# react-native-reanimated, pass component as prop with animated close

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component which uses `react-native-reanimated`, how can I add `hideSheet()` to the component I am passing as a prop?

```
import Animated, { Easing } from "react-native-reanimated";
...

const BottomSheet = ({
    children,
    ...
    renderHeader,...
}) => {
    const style = useMemo(
        () => getStyleObj({ backgroundColor, secondSnapshot }),
        [backgroundColor, secondSnapshot]
    );
    const [alignment] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
    const [alignmentChildren] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
    const WrapperComponent = tapToOpenEnabled ? Pressable : View;

    const openSheet = () => {
        Animated.timing(alignment, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 400,
            easing: Easing.bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1),
        }).start();
    };

    const hideSheet = () => {
        Animated.timing(alignment, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 400,
            easing: Easing.bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1),
        }).start();
    }; 
const toggleOpen = () => {
    if (open) {
        hideSheet();
        setOpen(false);
    } else {
        openSheet();
        setOpen(true);
    }
};
```

I am passing the header component as a prop:

```
  const renderSheetHeader = useCallback(() => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.headerCont}>
        <Text style={styles.headerTXT}>Setup your reminders</Text>
        <Icon name="closecircle" size={20} color={colors.GREYONE} *add hideSheet here* />
      </View>
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <BottomSheet
      ...
      renderHeader={renderSheetHeader()}
      ...
    >

return (
    <WrapperComponent>
       ...
                {renderHeader}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it as a parameter to your function.

```js
  const renderSheetHeader = useCallback((onHide) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.headerCont}>
        <Text style={styles.headerTXT}>Setup your reminders</Text>
              <View style={styles.headerCont}>
        <Text style={styles.headerTXT}>Setup your reminders</Text>
        <Pressable onPress={() => onHide()}>
            <Icon name="closecircle" size={20} color={colors.GREYONE} />
        </Pressable>
      </View>
      </View>
    );
  }, []);
```

Then, call it as usual.

```js
 <WrapperComponent>
       ...
                {(onHide) => renderHeader(onHide)}
```

In your `WrapperComponent`:

```js
renderHeader(hideSheet)
```

However, if it is not necessary that you define this as a function (and I do not see a reason in your current code), then you should be better of to just create a normale JSX component.

```js
export function SheetHeader(props) {
  return (
      <View style={styles.headerCont}>
        <Text style={styles.headerTXT}>Setup your reminders</Text>
              <View style={styles.headerCont}>
        <Text style={styles.headerTXT}>Setup your reminders</Text>
        <Pressable onPress={() => onHide()}>
            <Icon name="closecircle" size={20} color={colors.GREYONE} />
        </Pressable>
      </View>
      </View>
    );
}
```

and call it in your `WrapperComponent` directly.

```js
<SheetHeader onHide={hideSheet} />
```

Comment: I dont import the library in my file that contains renderSheetHeader. Is there a way I can attach the hideSheet function to the component? Or do I have to lift all the functionality up into that file?

Comment: I am afraid that I do not understand your response. What exactly is not working in the provided approaches above?

Comment: The BottomSheet has the onHide function, how can I add the onHide to the component Ive passed as a prop? Do I need to move the onhide up to the component I'm passing? Thanks